Eigenvalues of Hermitian quaternionic matrices
This is a question related to the Gaussian symplectic ensemble in random matrix theory. I know that the eigenvalues of the GOE and the GUE are all real, and it seems to be that this should be the case also for the GSE. Now the GSE is defined on the space of Hermitian quaternionic matrices. I know that the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix with complex entries are all real, but is the same true if the entries are quaternions? Is there an easy proof? I have searched the web but found nothing...
